# Three.js r71 is showing black screen when trying to load json object

Tags: three.js, 3dsmax, .obj

i will enumerate what i did until now:

1. I have a file "pre.obj" converted to "pre.js" using convert_obj_three.py script
   "pre.obj" uses "pre.mtl" because it has material of image "specular.jpg"

   "pre.obj" ,"pre.mtl" and "specular.jpg" can be looked at here respectivily

   xsportfit.com/threejs/pre.obj

   xsportfit.com/threejs/pre.mtl

   xsportfit.com/threejs/specular.jpg
2. I have tried to load "pre.js" file using three.js library of this way:

   ```
   var scene = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
   camera.position.z = 3;
   var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
   var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
   var mesh;
   jsonLoader.load('pre.js',function (geometry, materials) {
                       var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
                       mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                       scene.add(mesh);
                   }
           );

   var render = function () {
   requestAnimationFrame(render);
   renderer.render(scene, camera);
   };

   render();
   ```

Like you can see here http://xsportfit.com/threejs/ nothing is being showed, I am getting these warnings in console:

THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float_linear extension not supported.
three.js:11611 THREE.Loader: transparency has been renamed to opacity

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `materials` array contains an instance of `MeshLambertMaterial`. `MeshLambertMaterial` requires lights in the scene.

One option is to do this:

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
light.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );
scene.add( light );
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help until now, i have made some changes to the code using  `code`MeshLambertMaterial`code` instead of `code`MeshFaceMaterial`code`, i added light to scene  and added some rotation in render function , but my cube still without showing 'specular.jpg' image as texture of my cube, do you have any idea why? you can look at live here   http://xsportfit.com/threejs/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. _Do not_ change the question after it has been answered. Accept the answer by clicking on the check mark and make a new post if you have further questions.

Comment: `MeshLambertMaterial` does not take a materials array as an argument. Study the three.js examples and documentation.