# My model doesn't display it's texture with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have downloaded the following model from TF3DM : http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/sprite-bottle-91563.html

And i'm trying to display it in a scene with threeJS.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
light.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );
scene.add( light );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
// mtlLoader.setBaseUrl( '' );
mtlLoader.setPath( './' );
var url = "SpriteBottle.mtl";
mtlLoader.load( url, function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( './' );
    objLoader.load( 'SpriteBottle.obj', function ( object ) {

        object.position.y = - 95;
        scene.add( object );

    }, function() {}, function() {} );

});

camera.position.z = 5;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( render );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

With this code, nothing appears but the cube. I sometimes manage to display the bottle but the texture is not set.

EDIT: I have also tried to convert the obj file to JSON using the python script, and then applied the texture on it, it displays but not at the right spot.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Likely this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145339/three-js-r71-is-showing-black-screen-when-trying-to-load-json-object/32146564#32146564

Comment: Also, you are not loading the texture file and adding it to your material

Comment: @2pha yeah my bad i changed the code !

Comment: @WestLangley changed the light, didn't changed anything

Comment: Texture file path is hard coded into your .mtl file. It could be the problem.